# Data Science Modeling to predict safest stock 'sector' to invest in

Tags: python, data-science, data-modeling

Data Science Question: Created a DataFrame with stock sectors assigned to corresponding stocks. Sectors range from Misc., Tech, Real Estate…etc. How can I create and evaluate models such as Linear Regression, Random Forest, K-Nearest Neighbors, Support vector, RNN and LTSM to predict the safest sector to invest in (I was using standard dev./volatility as a continuous variable.)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBg3i.png)

This is what I had:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, precision_score, recall_score, f1_score

# Load the dataset
combined_df = pd.read_csv('/filepath...')

# Calculate the daily percentage change in stock price for each stock in each sector
combined_df['Daily_pct_change'] = combined_df.groupby(['Sector', 'Symbol']).   ['Close'].pct_change()

# Calculate the average daily percentage change in stock price for each sector
sector_avg_pct_change = combined_df.groupby('Sector')['Daily_pct_change'].mean()

# Determine which sector has the lowest average daily percentage change in stock price
safest_sector = sector_avg_pct_change.idxmin()

#Train linear regression model to predict the sector with the lowest average daily percentage   change in stock price
X = combined_df.drop(['Sector', 'Symbol', 'Daily_pct_change'], axis=1)
y = combined_df['Sector'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x == safest_sector else 0)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

#Evaluate the performance of the model
train_score = model.score(X_train, y_train)
test_score = model.score(X_test, y_test)

y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
y_pred = [1 if pred >= 0.5 else 0 for pred in y_pred]

accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
precision = precision_score(y_test, y_pred)
recall = recall_score(y_test, y_pred)
f1 = f1_score(y_test, y_pred)

print(f'Training R-squared: {train_score:.3f}')
print(f'Testing R-squared: {test_score:.3f}')
print(f'Accuracy: {accuracy:.3f}')
print(f'Precision: {precision:.3f}')
print(f'Recall: {recall:.3f}')
print(f'F1 score: {f1:.3f}')
```

Comment: And what happened when you ran this?

Comment: What are you expecting this to do?  You have already established the "safest sector" in your code long before you ever do any training or modelling.  What information is the model going to supply you?